# How to use your own database structure in Grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

We have an Android-Application communicating with a MySQL database via SOAP.

Now we were forced to create a webpage with Grails and of course we want to use the same database. 
But how can we tell Grails to use our database structure for the domains?
Is there a way to merge these systems?

(The connection to the MySQL-Database is already established, but the two structures do not work together)

e.g. (in the least complicated case) we have a table "locations" with just one column *'name'* which is PK. Grails would create a structure for the domain "location" with three columns *'id' 'version'* and *'name'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) allows you a lot of configurations, you can disable the version control, change your primary key mapping and so on. In your example:

```
class Locations {
  String name

  static mapping = {
    id column: 'name' //change the id from "id" to name
    version false //remove version control, so it will not be added to your table
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails creators had already thought about you and your case which is a common scenario when someone tries to move to grails with an existing enterprise infrastructure.

You need to have a look at [db reverse engineer plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) which creates domain classes based on the existing table structure. You can use the domain classes once created by the plugin.

You can access your MySQL db by providing the datasource as such. In general, company wide datasource would be maintained (or you can create one if required), and use the datasource in `Datasource.groovy`.